# How to mock XConnectClient

Tags: xconnect, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for a class that uses `XConnectClient`, which means I need to mock an `XConnectClient`.

I've tried the following using [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) and [RandomTestValues](https://github.com/RasicN/random-test-values) packages:

```
Mock<XConnectClient> client = new Mock<XConnectClient>(
    new Mock<XConnectClientConfiguration>(
        new Mock<XdbModel>(
            "XdbName",
            new XdbModelVersion(RandomValue.Int(), RandomValue.Int()),
            new XdbNamedType[0],
            new XdbFacetDefinition[0],
            new XdbModel[0]).Object,
        new Mock<Uri>(RandomValue.Uri().ToString()).Object).Object);
```

This compiles, but generates a `NullReferenceException` in `XConnectClientConfiguration.ctor` at runtime. I don't know what is NULL here, and there's really too much going on in the mocking so it's not easily readable any more.

Is there a way of mocking `XConnectClient` (preferrably without having to write a wrapper around it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to run your code by not mocking `Uri`, but by

```
                Mock<XConnectClient> client = new Mock<XConnectClient>(
                new Mock<XConnectClientConfiguration>(
                    new Mock<XdbModel>(
                        "XdbName",
                        new XdbModelVersion(1, 0),
                        new XdbNamedType[0],
                        new XdbFacetDefinition[0],
                        new XdbModel[0]).Object,
                    new Uri("https://dummy.xconnect")).Object);
```

However, if your intention is to verify returned contacts/interactions, then it won't help as those properties cannot be overridden on xConnectClient:

```
            /* 'Unsupported expression: x => x.Contacts
                Non-overridable members (here: XdbContext.get_Contacts) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'
            */
            client.Setup(x => x.Contacts).Returns(new List<Contact>
            {
                new Contact(new ContactIdentifier("test", "1", ContactIdentifierType.Anonymous))
            }.ToAsyncEnumerable().AsAsyncQueryable());
```

A better option to consider would be to mock `IXdbContext` that `XConnectClient` implements:

```
            var client2 = new Mock<IXdbContext>();
            client2.Setup(cn => cn.Contacts).Returns(new List<Contact>
            {
                new Contact(new ContactIdentifier("test", "1", ContactIdentifierType.Anonymous))
            }.ToAsyncEnumerable().AsAsyncQueryable());
            
            var c = client2.Object.Contacts;
            Console.WriteLine(c.Count().Result);
            
            c.ForEach(contact => 
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", contact.Identifiers.Select(id => id.Source))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the `IXdbContext` suggestion. That looks like exactly the way I need to go :)

Comment: @GTHvidsten good to hear that you found it helpful :)