# How to mock XConnect contact

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets, unit-testing, contact

I'm writing unit tests and using Moq as a mocking tool. In a [previous question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26921/how-to-mock-xconnectclient) I was advised to use `IXdbContext` to mock the XConnect client, which works just fine. However, I run into problems if I mock the `GetAsync()` method to be able to get a `Contact`.

I need to get facets off of the returned `Contact` so I either have to mock a `Contact` and override the `GetFacet<>()` method, or create a real `Contact` instance with the proper facets in its `Facets` collection.

The first option fails because `Contact` is sealed, and the second option fails because the `Facets` collection is a `ReadOnlyDictionary` which can't be written to.

So how can I properly mock a `Contact` that I can return in `GetAsync()` so that I can get facets out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with the second option (real `Contact` instance), you can use reflection (e.g. `ReflectionUtil`) to set `FacetMap` property on the contact instance.

`FacetMap` is then used by `Facets` and `GetFacet` calls.

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
       var contact = new Contact();

        var facetMap = new Dictionary<string, Facet>();
        var firstName = "Marek";

        facetMap[PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey] = new PersonalInformation
        {
            FirstName = firstName
        };

        Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(contact, "FacetMap", facetMap);

        Assert.AreEqual(firstName, contact.GetFacet<PersonalInformation>().FirstName);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using reflection for testing, but for lack of better options it seems that's my only choice. Thanks for the code example!